# Display query which SSMS executes from Interface/WYSIWYG edits

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If I am to add a new column to a table in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 via the interface/WYSIWYG (as opposed to writing a SQL query) this will, behind the scenes, create a SQL query which it will execute to perform the requested changes.

Is there any way to capture these SQL queries so that I am able to easily execute them on another server, without using SSMS, or re-writing the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make the changes, there's a menu option "Table Designer".  Under there is the option to Generate a Change Script.

There's an option there to automatically generate the script on future changes too.

Comment: What dialog? When I click the save button, it just removes the "unsaved" asterisk from the current tab.

Comment: mea culpa - brain still not working.  I've updated my answer with the right answer.

Comment: There is also a button that looks like a script with a floppy disk. If you hover over it, it should read 'Generate change script'. The button is part of the table designer toolbar.

Comment: Spot on! Found the menu option and toolbar option, exactly what I was after

Comment: The problem with the toolbar is that it mightn't be visible / showing.  It's less likely that the menu option will be missing!